# How do I retrieve HTML POST data for manipulation in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I have the following html:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form runat="server">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

How do I retrieve the value in the "name" textbox posted back to the webserver to manipulate in ASP.NET WebForms?

(I know about the ASP.NET built-in controls and the possibilities with them, but I am looking for a "clean" solution without the use of built-in ASP.NET controls)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you can't, or don't want to use asp.net textboxes, then you can retrieve the name of a regular html textbox like this:

```
string nameTextPosted = Request.Form["name"];
```

Just note that textboxes created in this manner will not automatically persist their values across postbacks like asp.net textboxes will.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution would be to turn it into a server-side component and access it by it's name. e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox Id="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

...

string name = Name.Text;
```

Unless you have other reasons not to use a component, you'd only be making things much more difficult on your part for no justification.

Comment: Thank you!
I know about the built-in ASP.NET controls, but I am looking for a way to do it manually with "clean" HTML.

Comment: @Alex It is clean html. Once they are rendered, they are html text boxes.

Comment: I know that too :-)
The reason why I'm not using the built-in controls is to "get my hands dirty" with the html part..

Answer (score 2):

ASP.net includes Html server controls for backward compatibility for just someone like you fond of html. make your html tags server controls by adding the runat="server" and id properties and you are able to access them inside your server side code with their id.

```
 <form runat="server">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="name1" runat="server" />
    </form>
```

Now after this you can control their behavior:

```
name.Value="Hellow World !"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add id and runat="server" in each control. like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" runat="server" />
```

Its better to use asp:TextBox  like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```